# Algorithm to clone a graph

Tags: algorithm, clone, graph-algorithm

Algorithm to clone a tree is quite easy, we can do pre-order traversal for that. Is there an efficient algorithm to clone a graph?

I tried a similar approach, and concluded we need to maintain a hash-map of nodes already added in the new graph, else there will be duplication of nodes, since one node can have many parents.

Comment: modified bfs/dfs where nodes are copied when they are marked as "visited" ?

Comment: Depends heavily on the data-structure.

Comment: [Graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) on wikipedia. Relatively big article that might give you something.

Comment: @Zeta Assuming graph is represented as Adjacency Matrix

Comment: @Keyser DFS/BFS with flag in original graph will help me to not visit the node again. But in the new graph i do want a link between the current node and a node already added in the graph. Since the already added node has more than one parents. Think of it as some social network graph where in you will have mutual friends.

Comment: If the graph is represented as an adjacency matrix, maybe you could just copy the matrix?

Answer (score 11):

It suffices to do a depth first search and copy each node as it's visited.  As you say, you need some way of mapping nodes in the original graph to corresponding copies so that copies of cycle and cross edges can be connected correctly.

This map also suffices to remember nodes already visited in the DFS.

So in Java you'd have something like:

```
class Node {

  // Contents of node...
  Data data;

  // ... member declarations like array of adjacent nodes
  final ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

  // Recursive graph walker for copying, not called by others.
  private Node deepCloneImpl(Map<Node, Node> copies) {
    Node copy = copies.get(this);
    if (copy == null) {
      copy = new Node(data);
      // Map the new node _before_ copying children.
      copies.put(this, copy);
      for (Node child : children)
        copy.children.add(child.deepCloneImpl(copies));
    }
    return copy;
  }

  public Node deepClone() {
    return deepCloneImpl(new HashMap<Node, Node>());
  }
}
```

Note that you *don't* want to override `equals` or `hashCode` for `Node`. The map containing copies relies on reference equality as defined by `Object`.

A different approach is to put an additional field in each node that points to the copy if there is one and is null otherwise.  This merely implements the map by another method.  But it requires two passes over the graph: one to make the copy and another to clear these map fields for future re-use.

Answer (score 3):

Your hash map approach seems viable if you had some quick way of uniquely identifying every node.

Otherwise, you would be best off if you:

1. used data-structure to store graph that allows you to store "is duplicated" **unique** flag directly in every node (for example, `0` not duplicated, `1`  to `numberOfNodes` for duplicated nodes),
2. traversed nodes (via BFS, DFS) taking care of the *already duplicated nodes* and *reconstructing all connections from the starting graph*.

Both your starting graph and finishing graph should have corresponding *unique* "is duplicated" flag in every node, so you are able to reconstruct connections from starting graph properly. Of course, you could use "is duplicated" flag and "unique identifier" as separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

As you copy nodes from the source graph, place each node in a `<Node, Integer>` map (thus numbering the nodes from 1 to N).

As you paste nodes in the destination graph, place each node in a `<Integer, Node>` map (again numbering from 1 to N, but with mapping in reverse direction for reasons that will be clear soon).

When you find a backlink in the source graph, you can map that backlinked "source copy" node to an integer `i` using the first map.  Next, you use the second map to lookup the integer `i` and find the "destination copy" node which needs to have the same backlink created.

Comment: I just realized this is pretty much the same answer Gene posted above, but with the Node<->Node map exploded into two maps.  Oh well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make the cloning efficient, use two things:

- DS with *faster deletion and addition* at end. Choose among `list`, `queue` or `stack`
- DS with *fast searching*. `Map` can be quickly searched i.e. `O(1)` amortized.

Algorithm:

```
                        To be processed <--> Queue
                          / 
Not_Cloned_Yet -> Clone it -> Map
      `~~~~~~~~checks~~~~~~~~~~^


Root is "Not Cloned yet" and needs to be "To be processed" -- (1)
Clone it -> Put in Map & Queue  -- (2)

Continue till "To be processed" is not zero. i.e. Queue is not empty. -- (3)
    Traverse and update the list of neighbours  -- (4)
        Neighbours that are "Not cloned yet" needs "Clone it -> Put in Map & Queue"   --(5)
```

1. Step 2 and 5 are based on `To be processed --> Queue`
2. Step 3 on `Queue -> To be processed`.
3. The queue elements are the ones which are already cloned, but NOT processed (i.e. its neighbours list not updated).
4. Neighbours may or may not have been cloned yet. So, check in map is needed.