# How To Copy A Full Non-Binary Tree Including Loops

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, binary-tree

Please share me your thoughts and any solution to this problem of copying the full non-binary tree, and it may include loops as well in which some of the children are connected to other parent nodes.

Example:
Here, "A" is the root or parent, and its children are "B" and "C" as usual, and at the end, child "G" is connected back to its grand-parent level "B", and similarly the "I" is connected to its immediate parent "C", so these are like a loops, and this also needs to be copied in the new tree as is.  So, here we need **additional logic to identify the loops** while copying the children nodes, and **not getting into an infinite loop**, and eventually return the copy of the whole tree.

```
A
 - B
   - D
   - E
     - F
     - G --> B
 - C
   - I --> C
   - K
```

This class or node structure can be like this:

```
public class Node{
  private String value;
  private List<Node> childrens;

  public Node copyTree(Node root) {
    ...
    //return
  }
}
```

Thanks for our help.

Comment: If there is a loop I don't believe it is a tree anymore, it is a graph. It seems you want to clone a graph. You may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536702/algorithm-to-clone-a-graph) to see how a graph can be cloned.

Comment: A tree that has cycles is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most direct way of doing this is to keep a map from nodes that have been copied to their copies. Then just check against the map before making a new copy of a node. Something like this (untested) should work:

```
public static Node copyTree(Node root) {
    return copyTree(root, new HashMap<>());
}

private static Node copyTree(Node root, Map<Node, Node> images) {
    Node copy = images.get(root);
    if (copy == null) {
        copy = new Node();

        // register the copy before recursing on children
        images.put(root, copy);

        // now fill in the copy
        copy.value = root.value;
        copy.children = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node child : root.children) {
            copy.children.add(copyTree(child, images);
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```